# EF Database first: disable lazyloading in a sustainable way

Tags: c#, entity-framework, ef-database-first

I'm just taking first steps with C# and EF and have an existing db which I'm importing as an EF data model into my Web API project. I discovered that lazy loading is enabled and some of my queries are consequently very slow. I therefore wish to disable it by manually removing the "virtual" keyword from the navigation properties in the generated models.

As I understand it, each time I make a schema change in the db I will need to re-generate the whole EF data model which will overwrite the models where I removed the virtual keyword meaning that I will have to do it again. Is there a way to configure EF to disable lazy loading by default? I found several posts relating to this, e.g. putting this into my db context ctor..

```
this.Configuration.LazyLoadingEnabled = false;
```

but none of the solutions offered seem to work.

Comment: IMHO Theoretically, you should never regenerate your EF data model. You generate it once, and update it several times, as much as necessary. But I know that some times things happens and we need to re-generate the whole model again, and all manual changes go to the space. I recommend you to use EF Code-First. VS will generate all of classes, so you can change them as you want. It works a lot better than EDMX

Comment: @FabioLuz Although I'm suggesting the use of the EDMX designer to update the model below (per OP requirements), I concur with the "use EF Code-First" recommendation. It works great if EF migrations can subsequently be used. Otherwise, the EF model can't be tweaked easily unless all changes to the DB are synchronized manually. For large projects, it probably has to be done that way anyway, but for smaller projects DB-First still offers a reasonable compromise.

Comment: @tne I understand your opinion, and you're right. For smaller projects DB-First offers a reasonable compromise. However, the OP wants to change some classes, and keep that change. If for some reason, he needs to delete the model and create it again (which is not uncommon), he will lose all the changes. That's why I believe that Code-First would be a better approach in that situation.

Comment: @FabioLuz Notice that I definitely agreed from the beginning. However, your last comment intrigues me; you'd lose your tweaks by regenerating the code-first model too (which you can't just update automatically), so is it really different in *that* regard? Again, for large projects updating manually is definitely OK, and maybe you implicitly mean that regenerating and merging back C# code is easier that merging EDMX with source control tools, to which I would agree too (having tried just about every approach).

Comment: @tne I was not clear enough about my opinion. I wanted to say that, sometimes EDMX model has to be deleted and created again (depending on the change made in DB. I say this because it happened with me, several times. EDMX has some bugs and do not understand some kinds of changes. For example, take a look at this thread I answered a few days ago http://goo.gl/OVg1hK). In code-first it doesn't happen, because the classes don't need to be regenerated. So, my statement is: "If manual changes in EDMX code is necessary; It is better to use code-first.".

Comment: That's just my opinion. I haven't post as an answer because I know it doesn't fit as one.

Answer (score 1):

Add a class with the same name as of your `ApplicationDbContext` in the same folder where your `.edmx` file is created and mark it partial like

> public partial class ApplicationDbContext : DbContext

add a static method in that class which returns an object of your `ApplicationDbContext` like

> public static ApplicationDbContext Create()

and in the definition of this method create a new object of your `ApplicationDbContext` and set its `LazyLoadingEnabled` to `false` like

```
var applicationDbContext = new ApplicationDbContext();

applicationDbContext.Configuration.LazyLoadingEnabled = false;
```

and finally return the newly created object. So the code for your partial class will look like

```
public partial class ApplicationDbContext : DbContext
{
   public static ApplicationDbContext Create()
   {
     var applicationDbContext = new ApplicationDbContext();
     applicationDbContext.Configuration.LazyLoadingEnabled = false;
     return applicationDbContext;
   }
}
```

and use `ApplicationDbContext.Create()` in your application while accessing the database  rather than `new ApplicationDbContext()`

Answer (score 0):

You can modify the T4 templates used for model generation to your liking (these are the `.tt` files).

Comment: Doesn't the .tt template also get replaced when I re-import the database? or is there a way to sync my db schema design changes with the generated models which doesn't require complete regeneration of the .edmx?

Comment: @Xoundboy Good point, I just tested it by updating a model via the designer; good news: the templates are not overridden (they're generic, so I would've considered it a bug otherwise). Look for the `AccessibilityAndVirtual` method in your main `tt` and make it a no-op/identity function (`return accessibility`); this should do what you want.

Comment: ok, I've been using SSMS to design my db schema, not the EF designer. So if I modify the .tt file in the way you suggest I'd have to start using the designer to change the schema? Sorry - I'm very new to all this

Comment: @Xoundboy Not at all, and no worries, it's not exactly intuitive. Continue to use SSMS (or better SSDT w/ source control) to design the relational model first. Then, open the EDMX designer, right click and select "Update model from database" to reflect changes to the EF model. Finally, regenerate the class files using your modified template (automatic on save or build AFAIR).

Answer (score 0):

> I discovered that lazy loading is enabled and some of my queries are consequently very slow.

Are you sure that the lazy loading is really the problem? Normally, the lazy loading has no impact on the query performance, but it has a negative impact if you use it to load properties in a loop, after the query has been executed (N+1)

and for sure, if you put `Configuration.LazyLoadingEnabled = false;` it will deactivate it.

the problem is perhaps not the lazy loading, but the creation of the proxies. Try to put `ProxyCreationEnabled = false` in your constructor and check if it better (it will also disable the lazy loading). Otherwise, if your data is read only, you can also try to use AsNoTracking extension method when you execute your query.